# Rename [sketchapp] to [sketch]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

Please rename the tag [sketchapp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sketchapp) to [sketch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sketch) on StackOverflow.

[Sketch](https://sketch.com) (domain changed a while ago from `sketchapp.com` to `sketch.com`) used to be a macOS-only app with plugin capabilities (JavaScript and Objective-C) but has since become a toolkit across Mac and the web with cross-platform third party APIs around the document format ([JSON Schema](https://github.com/sketch-hq/sketch-file-format), [TypeScript](https://github.com/sketch-hq/sketch-file-format-ts)) and [Assistants](https://developer.sketch.com/assistants/) in addition to the plugin API.

- There are no questions for [sketch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sketch)
- Some have used [sketch-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sketch-3) as a synonym. Sketch 3 was marketed including the major version number. Following a change of versioning system the version number (currently on 70.6) was dropped from the name.

Comment: Yep and only 117 questions have to be retagged

Comment: Would it be easier to synonym [sketchapp] to [sketch]?

Comment: I don't know what's easier. From a users point of view however it should clear that [sketch] is the main tag, meaning [sketch-3] or [sketchapp] could also be considered synonyms if renaming is tricky.